# Boxplot of a list of pandas dataframes

Tags: pandas, boxplot

I have the next list of dataframes

list = [df1, df2, df3, df4]

All the dfs has the same structure

df = [col1, col2, col3]

I want to make a boxplot with the same column in each df but i cant, im trying with:

```
for df in dfs:
    df.boxplot(column='col1', subplots=True)
```

The solution is:

```
new_df = pd.concat(list, axis=1)
for column in new_df:
    df.boxplot(['col1'])
```

Comment: Do you want a boxplot for all of the data between the dfs aggregated together? Or do you want separate boxplots for each dataframe?

Answer (score 1):

You need to concat it.

```
df = pd.concat(lst)
```

And then plot:

```
for column in df:
    plt.figure()
    df.boxplot(['col1'])
```

Comment: Only plots one boxplot

Answer (score 1):

You can combine all of the dfs into one larger dataframe (rowwise concatenation), then create boxplots of all the columns using the built-in boxplot method since the default behavior is to create a boxplot for each column.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

np.random.seed(42)
df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,size=(100, 3)), columns=['col1','col2','col3'])
df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,size=(100, 3)), columns=['col1','col2','col3'])
df3 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,size=(100, 3)), columns=['col1','col2','col3'])
df4 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,size=(100, 3)), columns=['col1','col2','col3'])

dfs = [df1, df2, df3, df4]

## this will create a big dataframe composed of all the dfs
all_data = pd.concat(dfs, axis=1)

## this creates one boxplot for the first dataframe, loop through this
boxplot = all_data.iloc[:,0:3].boxplot()
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks but i want plot the col1 for each df in the same boxplot --> col1 col1 col1

Comment: Ah I see. So you want 4 separate boxplots then?

Comment: Yes, it is possible?

Comment: I found the solution with your idea, only use pd.concat(list, axis=1) and then plot the 4 boxplots

Comment: Awesome! Glad to hear it worked. I will update my answer as well.

Comment: But a new problem emerging, when i try df.boxplot(['col1'], labels=col_names) the plot dont shows the name in each boxplot